# Git pre-receive hook and submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

I have a pre-receive hook on a remote bare Git repo that will run tests, compress some files and generate a build ID when I do from my laptop:

```
 $ git push production master
```

The simplified version of the pre-receive hook is something likje this:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
# Export deployed branch to build directory
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR
git archive $newrev | tar -x -C $BUILD_DIR 
cd $BUILD_DIR
the_build_script.sh 
done
```

Now, I've added two submodules to the repo, and I can't find any documentation or example about how to handle this. I know that I should run before the build script:

```
# git submodule init
# git submodule update
```

But, as far as I know, that will get the submodules referred by the old revision code and not the ones referenced in the new pushed code still not committed to the remote repo.

Any idea or example on how to handle this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution that (for now) seems to be working, something like this solved it:

```
echo "Exporting repo and submodules for build process..."
git clone -l --recursive . $BUILD_DIR  
echo "Cleaning up git information..."
find $BUILD_DIR -name ".git" -exec rm -rf {} \; || true
```

Until I find a cleaner way to do it...this will do :-)